# Python Simulation

Tags: python, graphics

I am using the graphics.py library to generate a simulation of multiple balls falling from the top of the screen. The balls should 'bounce' off the bottom and then resume falling back down. The rate at which the ball falls is determined by its size.

Currently the program generates and drops the balls with appropriate rates but when they 'bounce' the continue upwards indefinitely instead of falling again.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Code is as follows:

```
from graphics import *
from random import randint, choice
from time import sleep

# Generate a graphics window and set the 0,0 to the lower left corner.
win= GraphWin("Falling Bubbles!",600,600)
win.setCoords(0,0,600,600)
cornerB1= Point(-100,-100)
cornerB2= Point(700,700)
Background= Rectangle(cornerB1, cornerB2)       #Create a white background
Background.setFill('white')
Background.draw(win)

# Distance function and check function used to determine if two bubbles will be generated overlapping
def dist(p1, p2):
    x1, y1 = p1.getX(), p1.getY()
    x2, y2 = p2.getX(), p2.getY()
    return ((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2)**.5

def check(center, radius, bubbles):
    overlapping= False
    bubble= [item[0] for item in bubbles]
    for i in bubbles:
        radiSum= radius + bubble[0].getRadius()
        if (dist(center, bubble[0].getCenter())< radiSum):
            overlapping= True

        return overlapping

# This function defines between 3 and 6 Circle objects with a random radius between
#   10 and 35 pixels and stores them in a list with the format [bubble, dx, dy]
def makeBubbles():
    bubbles = []
    colors = ['red','blue','green','pink','yellow','cyan']

    n= randint(3,6)
    for i in range(n):
        center = Point(randint(40,560),randint(540,560))
        radius = randint(10,35)
        while (check(center, radius, bubbles)):
            center= Point(randint(40,560),randint(540,560))

        newbubble = Circle(center,radius)
        newbubble.setFill(choice(colors))
        bubbles.append([newbubble,0,-.6])
    return bubbles

# This function accepts the list of bubbles with their dx, dy values as a parameter
# The function increases the speed of all bubbles in the list with smaller
#   bubbles should increasing proportionally faster than larger bubbles
# The function returns the moddified 'bubbles' list

def speed(bubbles):
    for bubble in bubbles:
        radius= bubble[0].getRadius()
        if radius<=15:
            bubble[2] -= 1.1
        elif 16<=radius<=25:
            bubble[2] -= 1.05
        else:
            bubble[2] -= 1.025
    return bubbles
# This function accepts the list of bubbles with their dx, dy values as a parameter
# The function determines it the bubble is too close to the bottom border of the Graphics window
#   reverses it’s dy value and simultaneously reduce it’s speed
# The function returns the moddified 'bubbles' list

def sink(bubbles):
    for bubble in bubbles:
        center = bubble[0].getCenter()
        radius= bubble[0].getRadius()
        y= center.getY()
        if y+ bubble[2]< radius:
            bubble[2] *= -.9
        if bubble[2]>0:
            bubble[2]*=.9
        if .7<bubble[2]<-.7:
            bubble[2]= 0
        bubble[0].move(bubble[1], bubble[2])
        time.sleep(.025)

# Main
def main():
    bubbles= makeBubbles()
    n= len(bubbles)
    x= 0
    for bubble in bubbles:
        bubble[0].draw(win)
    while True:
        speed(bubbles)
        sink(bubbles)
        x+= 1


main()
```

EDIT1: New line added balls slow down to stop when bouncing up

EDIT2: Follow Up Question. I need the generated bubbles to not overlap at all when being generated.

EDIT3: Code added to determine if balls are generated overlapping

Comment: Your speed function multiplies each bubble's current speed by a positive factor, so the bubbles all speed up in whatever direction they're moving. So if they're moving down, they move down faster. If they're moving up, they move up faster. You should probably be adding a fixed (negative) number instead if you're trying to model gravity.

Comment: Wow that fixed it. Follow up question. Any idea on how to keep it from generating overlapping balls

Comment: @Wyatt You can keep track of all the center Point objects you generate, and if the current list contains a matching Point position, then generate an additional random Point. Do this in a while loop so that it keeps generating Points while the current point position matches any other Points in the list you have.

Comment: @Wyatt The balls themselves will still be overlapping, but it's a guarantee that they will have different center points. If you want to avoid overlapping completely, do the same thing, but instead of checking whether or not the center points match, check if the distance between the center points is less than the sum of the radi of both bubbles; if so, you know they will be overlapping

Comment: @ Matt Coats I'm needing to completely avoid any overlap of the balls generated. Would the centerpoints been appended into a new list for this comparison or could it be done from the bubbles list

Comment: @Wyatt In that case I would use the bubbles list. Like I said in my second comment, go through the list of bubbles and check if the distance between the new center Point being generated and the current bubble in the list's center point is less than the sum of their radi. If it is indeed less, then they will be overlapping. However, there's no telling what will happen when the gravity takes over. For this, you'll need to implement collision detection between each bubble. Does that make sense?

Comment: @MattCoats Could you provide some pseudocode for the loop I'm having issues with figuring out exactly what you mean

Comment: @Wyatt I added it as an actual answer because it was rather long. Can you edit your original question to include the follow-up?

Answer (score 0):

**This is an answer to the follow-up question regarding avoiding bubble overlaps:**

Here is a half pseudo-code method for checking if a generated center and radius pair overlaps another bubble in the bubble list. Note that it is indeed pseudocode because I don't know python syntax very well. Also note that you'll need to implement a dist function that takes in two Point objects and calculates the distance between them.

```
def checkIfOverlapping(center, radius, bubbles):
   overlapping = false;
   for i in range(bubbles.length):
      radiSum = radius + bubbles[i].radius
      if (dist(center, bubbles[i].center) < radiSum):
         overlapping = true

   return overlapping
```

You can eliminate some of the work done by the for loop by converting it to a while loop and exiting if overlapping is determined to be true as well:

```
while (i < bubbles.length and !overlapping)
```

This is what your for loop would now look like when generating the bubbles:

```
for i in range(n):
   center = Point(randint(40,560),randint(540,560))
   radius = randint(10,35)
   while (checkIfOverlapping(center, radius, bubbles)):
      center = Point(randint(40,560),randint(540,560))

   newbubble = Circle(center,radius)
   newbubble.setFill(choice(colors))
   bubbles.append([newbubble,0,-.6])
```

The loop now regenerates center points until the bubble is not overlapping with any bubble currently in the list. You might also consider regenerating the radius in that while loop too, in case the original radius is so big that no non-overlapping point exists. This can lead to an infinite loop.

Comment: I attempted to implement this in my code but am having trouble getting the correct syntax to make it work properly. EDIT 3 reflects this

Comment: Figured out the syntax. EDIT 3 changed to reflect

Comment: One last pick at your brain since you've been so helpful. EDIT 4. When the dy is really small making the balls stop moving